# Using gdal-java of OSGeo4W

Tags: gdal, java, osgeo, osgeo4w

I would like to use gdal_polygonize and gdalinfo in java.
[This](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/GdalOgrInJavaBuildInstructions) site says: "Note that  OSGeo4W includes a gdal-java package and a Java runtime making it fairly easily to build local Java applications using GDAL." But how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the source code for a gdalinfo java implementation here - https://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/trunk/gdal/swig/java/apps/gdalinfo.java

The polygonize function should be available in the java bindings, you may look at the source of gdal_polygonize.py to see how it's used - http://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/trunk/gdal/swig/python/scripts/gdal_polygonize.py

Comment: thanks that looks promising. I included gdal-1.10.1.jar and created gdalinfo.java. I also configured eclipse according to [this](http://geoexamples.blogspot.de/2012/05/running-gdal-java.html) site but there is an error when i try to run it: Native library load failed.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no gdaljni in java.library.path
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.gdal.gdal.gdalJNI.AllRegister()V

Comment: Have you set the appropriate environment variables? Add the dir containing the gdal dlls to PATH. You may also need to set GDAL_DATA, GEOTIFF_CSV, GDAL_DRIVER_PATH and PROJ_LIB [env vars](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/ConfigOptions).

Comment: Ok so you mean I have to put them in the environment variables in sytem properties and not eclipse right? "...dir containing the gdal dlls to PATH" wich dlls? I have some in gdal/swig/java (like gdaljni.dll and ogrjni.dll) and some in OSGeo4W64\bin\gdalplugins (like gdal_GEOR.dll). Tried both and still got the same error. For GDAL_DATA I have OSGeo4W64\share\gdal and for GDAL_DRIVER_PATH OSGeo4W64\bin\gdalplugins ..The gdal.jar file I included into the build path of my eclipse-project is the bin\gdal\java of a download from [this](http://download.gisinternals.com/release.php) site.

Comment: Java needs to be able to find the native binaries, not just the jar. [Here](http://geoexamples.blogspot.com.au/2012/05/running-gdal-java.html) are some linux instructions, replace references to "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH etc..." with "SET PATH=etc...;%PATH%" from the command line, or set via the Windows environment variables GUI. Not sure about Eclipse, I don't use it, but you should be able to set up a run configuration with the appropriate variables.

Comment: thanks, I got it. [Here](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/gdal/swig/java/apps/) are even more examples and I could use gdal_polygonize as gdalinfo.